# Get Subscription key based on customerKey

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush, subscriber-key

I need subscriptionKey from salesforce marketing cloud based on other field(such as email, customerId). I want to create API in which I will pass value of those field and I would like to return SubscriptionKey. Is it possible? If so, how?

this way we can get other key based on subscriberkey but I want to do reverse form ID I want to retrieve subscription key

```
string requestID = null;
APIObject[] results = null;
SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart();
sfp.Property = "SubscriberKey";
sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.IN;
sfp.Value = new String[] { "1", "2", "8" };
// Retrieve the ID, SubscriberKey and EmailAddress for the Subscribers
RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
rr.ObjectType = "Subscriber";
rr.Properties = new string[] { "ID", "SubscriberKey", "EmailAddress" };
rr.Filter = sfp;
// You can retrieve subscribers from specific accounts
// rr.ClientIDs = ...
// Or, you can retrieve subscribers across the parent account and all sub accounts
// rr.QueryAllAccounts = true;
// rr.QueryAllAccountsSpecified = true;
string status = integrationFramework.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);
Console.Write(status);
Console.Write(results.Length);
```

Comment: You’re getting downvoted because you haven’t shown any attempts nor have formulated a specific question.   Your question can be answered by checking the api documentation. The answer your seeking is much longer than the purpose of this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I Solve this.
Hope this help someone else

```
        try
        {
            soapClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new FuelOAuthHeaderBehavior("accessToken"));
            string requestId;
            APIObject[] results;
            SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart();
            sfp.Property = "User_ID";
            sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
            sfp.Value = new string[] { "123456" };
            RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
            rr.Filter = sfp;
            rr.Properties = new string[] { "Salesforce_Subscriber_Key" };
            rr.ObjectType = "DataExtensionObject[dataextentionobjectkey]";
            string status = soapClient.Retrieve(rr, out requestId, out results);
            if (status != null && status.ToLower().Equals("ok"))
            {
                if (results != null)
                {
                    DataExtensionObject obj = (DataExtensionObject)results[0];
                    string subscriberKey = obj.Properties[0].Value;
                }
            }
            Console.Write(status);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.ToString();
        }
```